# Which one is correct? 他们是我的老师们/他们是我的老师

Tags: grammar, mandarin

家好
请问一下，这些句子哪个对，哪个不对 ?
Which one is correct and which one is wrong?

1. 他们是我的老师们 (两个以上的老师)
2. 他们是我的老师 (两个以上的老师)
3. 他们是我老师们 (两个以上的老师)
4. 他们是我老师 (两个以上的老师)
5. 他们是我的朋友们 (两个以上的老师)
6. 他们是我的朋友 (两个以上的老师)
7. 他们是我朋友们 (两个以上的老师)
8. 他们是我朋友 (两个以上的老师)

Thank you !

Answer (score 5):

These four are all authentic expression while the first one is the best choice if you are introducing your teachers to someone.

**他们是我的老师**

他们是我老师

他们是我的朋友

他们是我朋友

---

1.老师 or 朋友

Both are acceptable. But it's usually more natural to call your teachers 老师 instead of 朋友 because it sounds more polite and formal.

2.我的老师 or 我的老师们

It's more natural in the Chinese language to say 他们是我的老师 instead of 老师们 even though "teachers" make more sense than "teacher" when understanding the sentence in the way of English grammar. It's hard for me to provide a reason for that.

3.我的老师 or 我老师

我 and 我的 both mean "my". The omission of 的 makes it more colloquial. It's common to hear people say 我... to a friend. But again I guess 我的老师 would suits better because it sound more formal.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: You're welcome! Hope that would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

**老师们**和**朋友们**是泛指，**他们**是特指，所以"他们是老师们/朋友们"不正确。你可以说"他们是两名老师"。"两名老师"在这里限定了范围，而"老师们"没有限定范围。

"他们是我的老师/朋友"代表特定的人群"他们"是属于同一属性"老师"。

如果你想强调特定的人群整体，你可以说"他们都是我的老师"。

在口语中，我们可以省略'***的***'。 "他们都是我老师"听起来好像比"他们都是我的老师"多了一点点感情色彩，好像更亲切了一点。

Comment: 我都懂了 ! 非常感谢你的解释 ~

Answer (score 0):

```
All of them might be correct.
But in the sense of properness, we say:
他们是我[的]老师。
他们是我[的]朋友。
-- no 们
-- you can choose to use 的 or not, doesn't matter, both proper.

but, 们 is proper in subject.
我老师们都怎么怎么样。
some may say
我老师都怎么怎么样。
They both sound normal, but I think the former if more proper.
```

Comment: Thank you for your help.

Answer (score -2):

2 4 6 8 are right.

1 3 5 7 are a little bit weird.

Comment: Hi Zitong, thanks for posting, please consider adding some explanation to your answer, so that you can help the OP understand better. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you Zitong !